# Filtering date time range via file csv name

Tags: c#

I have a list of csv files where the naming convention is in *yyyymmddhhmm*.csv

```
201606131800.csv
201606132000.csv
201606140100.csv
201606140300.csv
201606140500.csv
201606140700.csv
201606140800.csv
```

I need to do a file filtering from yesterday 7pm to today 7am if today date is 14 June 2016

I need to achieve these csv with file name range from 13 June 2016 7pm to 14 June 2016 7am

```
201606132000.csv
201606140100.csv
201606140300.csv
201606140500.csv
201606140700.csv
```

I have written select today files.
How can I do a filtering by date which include yesterday 7pm to 11:59pm?

```
string[] FileList = Directory.GetFiles(csvpath, DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*.csv");
foreach (var fileName in FileList)
  { 
  \\file process code.
}
```

Comment: is the Name and creation time for a particular file are same?

Comment: Name will not be same, but creation time can be same. I cannot use filtering base on creation date.
eg
`201606131800.csv - 2016/6/14 1am`
`201606132000.csv - 2016/6/14 1am`
`201606140100.csv - 2016/6/14 1am`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the File name and created DateTime are same then you can use the following code to get the List:

For example CreationTime for a file named `201606132000.csv` will be `2016/06/13/ 20:00` and `201606140500.csv` will be `2016/06/14/ 05:00`

```
DateTime yesterdayTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.AddHours(19);
DateTime TodayTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(7);
List<FileInfo> FilesBetween7To7 = Directory.GetFiles("your path here")
                                           .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                                           .Where(y => y.CreationTime > yesterdayTime && 
                                           y.CreationTime < TodayTime)
                                           .ToList();
```

Or You can do a comparison with the name and select files using the following snippet;

```
DateTime yesterdayTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.AddHours(19);
DateTime TodayTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(7);
List<string> fileList = Directory.GetFiles(csvpath, "*.csv").ToList();
List<string> FilesInTheRange = new List<string>();
DateTime fileTime;
foreach (string file in fileList)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(file.Replace(".csv",String.Empty), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fileTime))
    {
        if (fileTime >= yesterdayTime && fileTime <= TodayTime)
            FilesInTheRange.Add(file);
    }
}
```

`FilesInTheRange` will contains the required files

Comment: Just a note, there are cases when the creation date time of a file changes such as when a file is downloaded from the web. But if it is a locally created file then there will be no issues.

Comment: @un-lucky which library to i need to include to use this
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None

Comment: @Jonathan : `using System.Globalization;`

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested code, but you would want to use TryParseExact and convert the filenames into datetime objects and compare based on your start and end datetime.

```
string dateTimeFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm";
string[] FileList = Directory.GetFiles(csvpath, DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*.csv");
int startHour = 19; // 7 PM
int endHour = 7; // 7 AM
DateTime startDT = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 

DateTime.Now.Day - 1, startHour, 0, 0);
DateTime endDT = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, endHour, 0, 0);
foreach (var fileName in FileList)
{ 
    DateTime fileDT = DateTime.Min;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(fileName, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyle.None, out fileDT))
    {
        if(fileDT >= startDT && fileDT <= endDT)
        {
            \\file process code.
        }       
    }
}
```